# Calculating the average of an array after the user inputs another number into the array

Tags: javascript, html

I have a score text field that a user must input between 0 and 100 to add to the array. After displaying the the results, the average of the numbers in the array should be calculated. However, whenever I input a number the average is completely off and really high. How do I fix this? (e.g. array[88, 98, 77, 88] and input the number 99, the average jumps to 7039)

My code:

```js
var scores = [88, 98, 77, 88];

var addScore = function() {
  var scoreInput = $("score").value;
  if (scoreInput.length == 0 || scoreInput > 100 || scoreInput < 0 || isNaN(scoreInput)) {
    alert("You must enter a valid score.");
  } else {
    scores.push(scoreInput);
  }
}

var displayResults = function() {
  var highest = Math.max(...scores);
  var total = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    total += scores[i];
  }
  var average = total / scores.length;

  var output = "<h2>Results </h2><br>Average Score = " + average + ;
  $("results").innerHTML = output;
};
```

Comment: Input values are *strings*. When you add two strings, like `"10"+"25"`, the result is `"1025"`. Try converting them to numbers before adding to the array. You could use `parseInt()`: `scores.push(parseInt(scoreInput))`, or for shorthand, the unary `+` operator: `scores.push(+scoreInput)`.

Comment: @TylerRoper 's answer is almost certainly the correct one.  Just wanted to point out there is an error that will prevent the code example from running: `var output = "<h2>Results </h2><br>Average Score = "+average+;` will produce a syntax error.  In the future, a snippet that reproduces the issue is very useful for the community in attempting to help you.

Comment: @TylerRoper got it, thank you!

Comment: @lena do you use jquery? If not what is te definition of `$(...)`  ?

Answer (score 2):

You array are receiving a string rather a number. You must to convert the user input to number using parseInt or parseFloat before make the maths.

```
var addScore = function () {
    var scoreInput = $("#score").value; // or ".score"
    scoreInput = parseFloat(scoreInput); // here. If not valid, returns NaN.
    if (scoreInput > 100 || scoreInput < 0 || isNaN(scoreInput)) {
        alert("You must enter a valid score.");
    } else {
        scores.push(scoreInput);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question said 0 is a valid input, so `!scoreInput` won't produce the correct results.

Comment: @Mamun Can't really tell that for sure from OP's example. He hasn't mentioned nor tagged jQuery, he isn't using query selector syntax inside the `$` method, and his error isn't consistent with the idea that it's an issue. I imagine he's simply using `$` as a shorthand for `getElementById`, ie `const $ = document.getElementById`. The edit was a bit presumptuous in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code to this:

```
var scores = [88, 98, 77, 88];

var addScore = function () {
    var scoreInput = $("score").value;
    scoreInput = parseInt(scoreInput);
    if (scoreInput.length == 0 || scoreInput > 100 || scoreInput < 0 || isNaN(scoreInput)) {
        alert("You must enter a valid score.");
    } else {
        scores.push(scoreInput);
    }
}

var displayResults = function (){
    var highest = Math.max(...scores);
    var total = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
    {
        total += scores[i];
    }
    var average = total/(scores.length);

    var output = "<h2>Results </h2><br>Average Score = " + average ;
    $("results").innerHTML = output;
};
```

It should work.

Changes made:

1. `scoreInput = parseInt(scoreInput);` in `addScore` function so that the value is first converted into an Integer before any comparison happens.
2. `var average = total/(scores.length);` in `displayResults` function to make it clear.
3. Cleaning up `"<h2>Results </h2><br>Average Score = "+average+;` to a correct and cleaner version. Note that you had a `+` in the end!

Answer (score 0):

You not defined $(...) function so I guess it is jquery. I fix a little your code:

- change var `scoreInput = $("score").value` to `$(".score")[0].value;`  (this will read input with ".score" class and cast it to number)
- change `$(".results").innerHTML` to `$(".results")[0].innerHTML`
- simplify if statement in `addScore`

```js
var scores = [88, 98, 77, 88];

var addScore = function () {
    var scoreInput = +$(".score")[0].value;

    if (isNaN(scoreInput) || scoreInput > 100) {
        alert("You must enter a valid score.");
    } else {
        scores.push(scoreInput);
        displayResults();
    }
}

var displayResults = function (){
    var highest = Math.max(...scores);
    var total = 0;
    
    for(var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
    {
        total += scores[i];
    }
    var average = total /scores.length;

    var output = "<h2>Results </h2><br>Average Score = "+average;
    
    $(".results")[0].innerHTML = output;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="score" type="number">
<button onclick="addScore()">add</button>

<div class="results">
```

Comment: Judging by OP's use of `innerHTML` and `.value`, the lack of query selectors, and jQuery not being tagged or mentioned, I'd venture to guess that OP's code is **not** using jQuery, but rather defines `$` as a shortcut for `getElementById`.

Comment: @TylerRoper he not define the $(...) function so I guess it is jquery

Comment: He also shows no HTML, never calls either of the functions, and says that he's getting an incorrect result (if he were using jQuery, the code wouldn't execute at all, rather than returning *any* result). I think it's safe to assume that there is other code. That said, OP would need to clarify, but I think it would be a good idea to mention that those tips only apply *if* OP is using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your code:

1. *scoreInput* is of type string. You have to convert that to number to perform actual arithmetic operation.
2. You have missed the *id* or *class* symbol (`#,.`) in the selector.
3. When use jQuery you have to use `val()` not `value` like `$("#score").val()`.
4. Similarly `$("results").innerHTML = output;` should be `$("#results").html(output);`

Try the following way:

```js
var scores = [88, 98, 77, 88];

var addScore = function () {
    var scoreInput = $("#score").val().trim();
    if (!scoreInput || scoreInput > 100 || scoreInput <= 0 || isNaN(scoreInput)) {
        alert("You must enter a valid score.");
        $("#score").val($("#score").val().slice(0, -1)); // Remove the last character
    } else {
        scores.push(Number(scoreInput));
        displayResults();
    }
}

var displayResults = function (){
    var highest = Math.max(...scores);
    var total = 0;
    
    for(var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
    {
        total += scores[i];
    }
    var average = total /scores.length;
    var output = "<h2>Results </h2><br>Average Score = "+average;
    $("#results").html(output);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="score" oninput="addScore()">

<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: I had mentioned this in a separate comment, but as far as I can tell we have no reason to believe that the `$` refers to jQuery in OP's case. It's  quite common common to [use `$` as a shorthand for the `getElementById` function](https://www.thoughtco.com/and-in-javascript-2037515). If OP were misusing jQuery selectors as you suggest, the error(s) would be much different.

Answer (score 0):

the calculation of an average, however, has nothing wizard ...

```js
var scores = [88, 98, 77, 88];

var average = scores.reduce((a,b)=>a+b) / scores.length;

console.log ( average );
```